# Determine Asp.net version of the web application deployed in IIS server with multiple .net framework versions

Tags: c#

Need to find which .net version is used by web application after its deployed in IIS server with multiple .net framework versions installed in it

My Asp.net web application is compiled with target framework 4.0 and deployed in IIS 10 server. In IIS server, application pool is configured to run with CLR version 4.0.30319.

In the Deployment server, .net framework 4.0 to 4.6.2 is installed. Found this from regedit.

In this case, how to find if the web application is running under the 4.0 framework or 4.6.2 framework ?

While printing the environment.version property in aspx page of the web app, the version displayed is 4.0.30319.42000.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed  "Microsoft Version Detection Link")

According to the above Microsoft link, 4.0.30319.42000 means .net framework version is 4.6 or above.

However, as per above link, environment.version property is not supposed to be used to identify the .net framework version post 4.5 series.

Hence confused how to find out the framework version under which web application is running ? Does it run with latest .net framework version ?  Any property or official method to find this.

Intention is to migrate the web application to run with latest target framework if it's running currently below 4.5.1 version as these are not officially supported.

Sorry for the long post but couldn't explain in less words.

Comment: *You* specify the version, in the `web.config` file. There's almost no chance your app will run on 4.0 - the older supported .NET 4.x version is 4.5.2. .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements which means that if an update is installed eg through Windows Update, all applications that target 4.x now run on the new runtime.

Comment: A better question would be, why do you want to know if 4.0 is used? And why do you target an unsupported runtime that can't even use TLS 1.2?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your statement that application will always run under the latest run time is the answer which i was looking for. Now to answer your question, there is a recent security alert that asp.net version running 4.0.30319 and not officially supported should be migrated to latest vesion. This lead me to investigation on all the old web applications deployed in the server. So i found 4.6.2 is installed but was not aware that previous framework version such as 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 etc is over written technically due to 4.6 binaries.